# In pandas df find if the True value in column A is his first occurrence since last True in column B

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I'm searching for the most efficient way to find if `True` value in `column A` is the first occurrence since last `True` value in `column B`.

In this examples the expected output would be `column C`.

**Example 1:**

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [False, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True],
    'B': [True, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False],
    'C': [False, False, True, False, False, False, True, False, False]
})
```

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | False | True | False |
| 1 | False | False | False |
| 2 | True | False | True |
| 3 | False | False | False |
| 4 | True | False | False |
| 5 | False | True | False |
| 6 | True | False | True |
| 7 | False | False | False |
| 8 | True | False | False |

**Example 2:**

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [True, False, False, True, False, True, False, True, False],
    'B': [False, True, False, False, False, False, True, False, False],
    'C': [False, False, False, True, False, False, False, True, False]
})
```

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | True | False | False |
| 1 | False | True | False |
| 2 | False | False | False |
| 3 | True | False | True |
| 4 | False | False | False |
| 5 | True | False | False |
| 6 | False | True | False |
| 7 | True | False | True |
| 8 | False | False | False |

**Example 3:**

Here you can find a [.csv file with a bigger example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRxtjjLHTlJ4O-rWFVST5nDy0pclK2tzCKCZFG6wE2xWiIKe5lP_tiFwb0SRzpjp3R1p4cBGea-S63a/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv)

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you walk through your example more clearly? What is your expected output?

Comment: I assume columns A and B are in the input and column C is created later.

Comment: @not_speshal Sorry if is not clear, as Arkadiusz set, the column C is the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `groupby` operation on the cumulative sum of column "B" to group your dataframe how you described. Then you can use `idxmax` to get the index where each of those first occurrences exist within column "A". Once you have those indices, you can create your new column "C".

Using `idxmax` is a little trick because we're not actually interested in the maximum value since column "A" only ever has `True` and `False` as its values. `idxmax` will return the index of the **first** occurrence of the maximum (in this case, the first occurrence of `True` within each group), which is what we're specifically interested in.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [False, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True],
    'B': [True, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False],
})

# get a dataframe of the position of the max as well as the max value
indices_df = df["A"].groupby(df["B"].cumsum()).agg(["idxmax", "max"])

# mask to filter out the 0th group
skip_0th = (indices_df.index > 0)

# mask to filter out groups who do not have True as a value
groups_with_true = (indices_df["max"] == True)

# combine masks and retrieve the appropriate index
indices = indices_df.loc[skip_0th & groups_with_true, "idxmax"]

df["C"] = False
df.loc[indices, "C"] = True

print(df)
       A      B      C
0  False   True  False
1  False  False  False
2   True  False   True
3  False  False  False
4   True  False  False
5  False   True  False
6   True  False   True
7  False  False  False
8   True  False  False
```

---

Updated for example 2.

We can resolve this issue by slicing our indices Series to exclude any entry whose index is 0 (e.g. label slicing from 1 to the end). This works because of our `groupby` operation assigns integer based labels according to the `.cumsum`. In example 1, the smallest index label will be 1 (since the first value in column "B" is True). Whereas in example 2, the smallest index label will be 0. Since we don't want the 0 to effect our results, we can simply slice it away from our `indices`.

When we assign "C" after performing the slicing on our `indices` Series, we will appropriately ignore all of the values from before the first occurrence of True in column "B".

Enough text though, lets see some code.

Example 1

```
print(indices)
1    2
2    6

# Slicing here doesn't change anything, since indices does not have
#  a value corresponding to label position 0
indices = indices.loc[1:]
print(indices)
1    2
2    6
```

Example 2

```
print(indices)
0    0
1    3
2    7

# we don't want to include the value from label position 0 in `indices`
#  so we can use slicing to remove it

indices = indices.loc[1:]
print(indices)
1    3
2    7
```

Comment: Thank you Cameron, this is really what i was searching for but I've tried in my code and I've found a case where is not working as expected. I've edited the question, can you please check it?

Comment: Just updated the code to correct for this. Let me know if the explanation isn't clear or if there are any other edge cases.

Comment: @CameronRiddell thank you for the update. Unfortunately in the `Example 3` this solution is not working :(

Comment: Ah, I was assuming that each group would have at least 1 True value. Updated the code to account for that by filtering out indices that belonged to groups that did not have at least 1 True value.

Comment: @CameronRiddell Thank you very much, this is working perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to do it, maybe not the best one.

```py
is_occurred = False
def is_first_occurrence_since(column_to_check, column_occurence):
    global is_occurred
    if is_occurred and column_to_check == True:
        is_occurred = False
        return True
    elif not is_occurred and column_occurence == True:
        is_occurred = True
    return False
df.apply(lambda row: is_first_occurrence_since(row['A'], row['B']), axis=1)
```

Comment: Include this in your question if it isn't an answer

Comment: It is an answer and the result is correct but I don't know if is the better way to do it.